Increasing LCL antenna tuning bandwidth 779MHz-928 MHz
I want to tune a helical antenna to a bandwidth between 779-928 MHz, the center frequency is 853.5 MHz. Before this, I set up an LCL tune circuit and observe the S11 parameters. S11 reflections are quite good in narrow band, but the bandwidth is quite narrow. What should I do to expand the bandwidth at 779-928 MHz?



Your schematic doesn't identify values nor is it clear about which port the antenna is located at and, what interface impedance is required. Details of the antenna impedance across the required bandwidth. All this info is needed.

Your L-C-L network tends to have a Q greater than needed (hence, narrower bandwidth). You may be able to use an L-C network having lower Q. And two cascaded L-C networks can give even lower Q. Low-Q networks also tend to reduce losses. Nevertheless, we can't tell if your bandwidth requirement can be met.
